# OnResume in phonegap plugin?

Tags: android, cordova

How to use onresume() , onPause() methods of android in phonegap plugin for android?
As a newbie for android i know that we can override those methods in MainActivity.java .But I am calling phonegap exec method to call android plugin in Phonegap.In this plugin how to use onResume() method?? Any help?
OnResume() I want to request location update using phonegap plugin in android

Answer (score 0):

The resume event is not in phonegap.js because it's fired from the native side

Comment: That is what my question is about . How to use resume event inside exec method of native code?Because after gps icon stops blinking android is not requesting any location updates,So I am getting only first location data.I think i must request location onresume also